# How to automate python for creating graphs in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wan't to be able to create a function in python which automatically produces graphs of all the countries in my dataframe. I have given the countries specific number codes from 1 to 211 in my CSV file. How can i make that happen? Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandasql import sqldf
import pandasql as pdsql
import pandasql as psql
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

covid = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Test/Desktop/covid.csv")

covid =  psql.sqldf("select co, new_deaths from covid where co= 'Canada'")


covid['MA_5'] = covid.new_deaths.rolling(5).mean()
covid['MA_10'] = covid.new_deaths.rolling(10).mean()

plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(covid['new_deaths'],label='new_deaths')
plt.plot(covid['MA_5'], label='MA 5 day')
plt.plot(covid['MA_10'], label='MA 10 day')
plt.legend(loc=2)
```

I have already created a graph for Canada but would like to make one for all the countries. How can I automate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandasql import sqldf
import pandasql as pdsql
import pandasql as psql
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

countries = ["canada", ... , "japan"]

covid = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Test/Desktop/covid.csv")

for country in countries:
    covid = psql.sqldf(f"select co, new_deaths from covid where co= '{country}'")

    covid['MA_5'] = covid.new_deaths.rolling(5).mean()
    covid['MA_10'] = covid.new_deaths.rolling(10).mean()

    plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.plot(covid['new_deaths'],label='new_deaths')
    plt.plot(covid['MA_5'], label='MA 5 day')
    plt.plot(covid['MA_10'], label='MA 10 day')
    plt.legend(loc=2)`
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code works fine but when using plot.imshow() it gives me this error : TypeError: imshow() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'.  Also i would like to save the individual graphs in a folder on my desktop. How can i do that?

Comment: plt.imshow displays the image on the axes, but if you need to display multiple images you use plt.show() to finish the figure.

Comment: @Weeaboo This site uses a model based on **one answer per question**. You created a post, asked a question and got a really good answer with working sample code. That's a job well done for both of you!  If you want to ask more questions, feel free to create new posts to ask them. What you are trying to do here might be seen as someone who is trying to get free freelance work done. Just be careful and follow the site's model.